# Imap : Fetch Email -> Forward Email

Tags: python, smtp, imap

I'm trying to fetch the lastest email received **(successfully done)** and to forward it to other address.

I'm not looking to send it like a normal email using : `smtp.sendmail(FROM_ADDRESS, TO_ADDRESS, msg.as_bytes())`

I'm looking to **forward** it .

The differences between normal send and a forward as i noticed till now are :

Source Email (normale send) :

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"


Body of email
```

Source Email (forward send) :

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

---------- Forwarded message ---------
From: Ha <ha@gmail.com>
Date: Fri, May 28, 2021 at 2:28 PM
Subject: Hello forward
To:


Body of email
```

This is what i've done so far : A script that fetch the lastest email received on my inbox

```
import imaplib
import email
import time

IMAP_HOST = "imap.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT = 587

USERNAME = "myemail@gmail.com"
PASSWORD = "mypwd"
SEARCH_CRITERIA = "ALL"

FROM_ADDRESS = "myemail@gmail.com"
TO_ADDRESS = "To@gmail.com"

FORWARD_TIME_DELAY = 5
EXCEPTION_TIME_DELAY = 60
VERBOSE = True



# Open IMAP connection
imap_client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IMAP_HOST)
imap_client.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

# Fetch messages' ID list
status, _ = imap_client.select("INBOX", readonly=True)
if status != "OK":
    raise Exception("Could not select connect to INBOX.")

status, data = imap_client.search(None, SEARCH_CRITERIA)
if status != "OK":
    raise Exception("Could not search for emails.")

messages_id_list = data[0].decode("utf-8").split(' ')
messages_id_list = messages_id_list[0]      # edited
if VERBOSE:
    print("{} messages were found. Forwarding will start immediately.".format(len(messages_id_list)))
    print("Messages ids: {}".format(messages_id_list))
    print()

# Fetch each message data
messages_sent = []
while len(messages_sent) < len(messages_id_list):
    msg_id = messages_id_list[len(messages_sent)]

    status, msg_data = imap_client.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
    if status != "OK":
        raise Exception("Could not fetch email with id {}".format(msg_id))
```

Comment: Your not using the Gmail api you are using the smtp server there is a difference, you will have better luck getting answers if you tag and label your question properly.

Comment: This is not a simple thing to do: you have to cope with many different messaging layouts, HTML emails, etc.  Even full featured email clients get this wrong sometimes.  But roughly, you’ll need to find “the body/bodies”, prepend your forwarded header (in both HTML and plain Text mode!), reconstruct the message, serialize that as bytes, and send that.  There’s no built-in stuff for editing bodies (or even finding the bodies), and HTML can be challenging since you can’t just put it anywhere.